# Use jQuery to generate PrimeFaces button clicked, but the click event get called over and over

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

Here is what I try to accomplish. I have a hidden form with two JSF inputText and a button. Wherever i click inside a `div` container, I will try to calculate the `x` and `y` coordinate relative to my container. Then use jQuery to set the value of `x` and `y` to the value of the two JSF inputText and submit the form. A managed bean behind the JSF page will try to catch the value of x and y submit.

Below are my codes. Please let me know what I did wrong, because method `createNewInput` inside managed bean `myBean` did not **correctly** get invoked.

**EDIT2**

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head"/>        
<div id="result">Click an Element</div>
<div id="pdfCol">
    <h:form>
        <h:outputText value="#{note.test}"/>
        <p:commandButton actionListener="#{myBean.createNewInput}" value="Submit"/>  
        <!-- This button is to see when I click, whether the method inside managed bean get invoked. And it did. By looking at the log files.-->
    </h:form>

</div>
<div id="noteCol">            
    <h:form style="display:none;" prependId="false">
        <h:inputText id="coordX" value="#{myBean.newInputXCoordinate}"/>
        <h:inputText id="coordY" value="#{myBean.newInputYCoordinate}"/>
        <p:commandButton id="button" actionListener="#{myBean.createNewInput}" value="Submit"/>
    </h:form>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery("#noteCol").click(function(e){
        var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
        e.stopPropagation();                
        jQuery("#result").text(this.id + "Offset: (" + offset.left + ", " + offset.top + "), " + 
                "Relative Coordinate: (" + (e.pageX - offset.left) + ", " + (e.pageY - offset.top) + ")");

        jQuery("#coordX").val(e.pageX - offset.left);
        jQuery("#coordY").val(e.pageY - offset.top);

        jQuery("#button").click();
    });
</script>
```

On the server side, I print out the pair of coordinates when the method `createNewInput()` in the managed bean `myBean` is invoked. And gladly, I see the correct result of the two coordinates. However, **it keep printing this pair of coordinates over and over again, but the values of the pair of the coordinates are `NaN` after correctly print out the first time.** However do I fix this?

Comment: You have the `jQuery("#button").click(function(e)...` inside `jQuery("#noteCol").click(function(e)...`, I don't think that's what you wanted to do. The code you wrote means: when #noteCol is clicked change #button's onclick event handler to a new function. The new function won't be called right now, only when you click on the #button.

Comment: @adam: how do I fix so that, when i click on `#noteCol`, the `#button` will be clicked as well.

Comment: As BalusC said, `jQuery("#button").click();` should work. Be sure to remove `jQuery("#button").click(function(e)...` too. Also don't keep on changing the example, `p:commandButton` and `h:commandButton` is not the same. In case of a simple `h:commandButton` you should use `jQuery("#button").closest("form").submit();
`, in case of `p:commandButton` use `jQuery("#button").click();`.

Comment: @adam: Thank you. It make a lot more sense to me now. I still have another question for you. So I am using `p:commandButton` with `jQuery("#button").click()` and on the server side, i print out the two coordinates. It works, but after successfully print out the first pair of coordinates, it continue to print out these coordinates over and over again, but the value of these coordinates are `NaN`. Any idea why and how to fix this, Adam?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my problem. The problem is the click event got bubble up. So in order to stop this

```
jQuery("#noteCol").click(function(e){
    var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
    e.stopPropagation();                
    jQuery("#result").text(this.id + "Offset: (" + offset.left + ", " + offset.top + "), " + 
                "Relative Coordinate: (" + (e.pageX - offset.left) + ", " + (e.pageY - offset.top) + ")");

    jQuery("#coordX").val(e.pageX - offset.left);
    jQuery("#coordY").val(e.pageY - offset.top);

    jQuery("#button").click();
});

jQuery("#button").click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you get a `NaN`. Where do you see it? Also, it makes more sense to me if you calculate `e.pageX - offset.left` instead of the other way round. Further, setting input element's value in jQuery should be done by [`jQuery.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function.

Also, JSF will prepend the generated HTML input element ID with the form ID which will cause that `jQuery('#coordX')` returns nothing. jQuery takes HTML element IDs, not JSF component IDs. You want to add `prependId="false"` to the `<h:form>` to disable that. But you should ensure that the same input components does not appear more then once in the output and that you don't have any other parent `UINamingContainer` components on the input components which will prepend their ID as well, to verify this you need to check if the generated HTML `<input type="text">` has indeed the `id="coordX"` as you're attempting to select by jQuery.

Finally, the `jQuery.submit()` only works on HTML `<form>` elements, not on buttons. For that you rather want to use `jQuery.click()` instead.

So, summarized this should in theory work for you:

```
<div id="noteCol">
    <h:form prependId="false" style="display:none;">
        <h:inputText id="coordX" value="#{myBean.newInputXCoordinate}"/>
        <h:inputText id="coordY" value="#{myBean.newInputYCoordinate}"/>
        <h:commandButton id="button" actionListener="#{myBean.createNewInput}"/>
    </h:form>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery("#noteCol").click(function(e){
        var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
        e.stopPropagation();                
        jQuery("#result").text(this.id + "Offset: (" + offset.left + ", " + offset.top + "), " + 
                "Relative Coordinate: (" + e.pageX + ", " + e.pageY + ")");

        jQuery("#coordX").val(e.pageX - offset.left);
        jQuery("#coordY").val(e.pageY - offset.top);

        jQuery("#button").click();                
        // Or:
        // jQuery("#button").closest("form").submit();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The reason why I got `NaN` is because I try to do something like this `Jquery("#result").text("..." + e.pageX - offset.left + "...")`, i forgot to put the `()` around `e.pageX - offset.left`. However i still cant get the method in my managed bean to be invoke. I add this `jQuery("#button").submit(function(e){
                    alert("Button submit");
            }); ` to see if `button` get submit, and I see no alert box come up. Any idea why, BalusC?

Comment: btw. I did check the generated HTML and there are components with id `coordX`, `coordY` and `button`. I changed my codes a bit. I re-updated my original post to reflect that.

Comment: The `submit()` only works on `<form>`. On `<input type="submit">` you rather want to use `click()`.

Comment: I actually tried that as well. And I add a call back function that will invoke an alert box when the button is click (refer to my edited code in my original post). The alert box never come up. I take `style="display:none"` out of the form, and I see the `inputText` values are correctly set. If I manually click the button, then the alert box show up. So weird.

Comment: Oh, it's now `p:commandButton` instead of `h:commandButton`? What do you really have? The `form.submit()` isn't going to work when a button is ajax-enabled. Use `button.click()` without any alert function. Just so `jQuery("#button").click();`. You're otherwise basically overridding the PrimeFaces default ajax `onclick` function on the button.

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to confused you there with `p:commandButton`. I was just testing out couples different things. So now I went back to your above code with `h:commandButton`. If I dont have `jQuery("#button").click()`, then I both my inputText get the correct coordinates set. If I manually click the button, then on the server side log, I can print out the two coordinates. If I put in `jQuery("#button").click()` and try again, now both of my inputText get `NaN` value, and the log file on the server side record that, the button was not clicked.

Comment: Re-reading Adam's comments and yours, I decide stick with `p:commandButton` and I use `jQuery("#button").click()`. On the server side, I print out the pair of coordinates when the method is invoke(). And gladly, I see the correct result of the two coordinates. However, it keep printing this pair of coordinates over and over again, but the values of the pair of the coordinates are `NaN` after correctly print out the first time. Any idea how to fix it, BalusC?

Comment: I figure it out, it is because the click event was bubbled up. In order to stop this, I have to use `stopPropagation();`. I post the solution as a separate post.